# Combine smaller png files in a larger png file in C++

Tags: c++, png

I have a bunch of png images of known sizes, that are part of a larger image. I know where the images are to be placed to construct the whole image, i.e., I know the top left coordinate for each sub-image. How do I construct the larger image in C++? Are there any libraries that can do this for me? Links to any example code would be great too.

Answer (score 0):

Try [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/), specifically the [Magick++](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick++.php) API.

If you're targeting only one platform (say Windows), there might be simple solutions that do not require a library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The CImg Library](http://cimg.eu/). It's a lightweight library, consists of few files. The main file is *CImg.h*.

There is the *draw_image* function which draw another image over the current one - this is exactly what you need.

Here is the declaration:

```
template<typename T>
struct CImg {
// ..... other code

//! Draw an image \overloading.
template<typename t>
CImg<T>& draw_image(const int x0, const int y0, const CImg<t>& sprite, const float opacity=1);

// ..... other code
};
```

*(x0=width pos, y0=row position* is the starting position in the original image where you want to draw the *sprite* image.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `OpenCV`.

First, you'd have to open all the small files (explained [in the tutorial here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/load_save_image/load_save_image.html)) and store them as `cv::Mat`s. After all your small images are open you can put them all together to a greater image by copying them to specified regions.

When you're done putting together those images just use `imwrite` like in the link above to save the new image to a png file.

Example code where to images are put together horizontally one next to another (hence the max number of rows):

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // check if arguments were given correctly
    cv::Mat img1 = cv::imread(argv[1]);
    cv::Mat img2 = cv::imread(argv[2]);
    // load more images if necessary
    // If images have alpha channel then use CV_8UC4
    cv::Mat whole = cv::Mat((img1.rows<img2.rows?img2.rows:img1.rows), img1.cols+img2.cols, CV_8UC3);
    img1.copyTo(whole(cv::Rect(0, 0, img1.cols, img1.rows)));
    img2.copyTo(whole(cv::Rect(img1.cols, 0, img2.cols, img2.rows)));
    // add more images if necessary
    imwrite("whole.png", whole);
    return 0;

}
```